# Target single post in a specific category

Tags: wordpress

I want to target CSS in a single post in a specific category. I'm on Wordpress ofcourse.

As far as I know (and tried) we can only do this on category archive page, and not single post

Answer (score 0):

you need to hook into wp_footer by using below code to append css in the footer for specific post of category.

`12` is the id specific post. you need to change the id of post you where the css needs to call.
`is_category('categoryname')` check category by category slug/name.

```
add_action('wp_footer',function(){
global $post;
if(is_category('categoryname') && $post->ID == 12 )
echo '<style type="text/css">.change_color:{color:red}</style>';
})
```

If you have custom taxonomy use..

change parameters as per the need. this function will  check if your current post has specific category it will change color of your selector.

```
add_action('wp_footer',function(){
    global $post;
    $cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
    if( has_term( $cat_id , 'my_custom_post_type' ) )
    echo '<style type="text/css">.change_color:{color:red}</style>';
    })
```

Comment: Thanks Noman but the above edit would require me to edit (and add) new set of code for every new post I do, no? What I want One CSS for all the post in specific category, hopefully it will make sense.

Comment: @IrfanSaleem second part of the code will does for all the posts if has specific categories.
`has_term` will check every post if it has the specific category. it means one css rule for every posts having the category

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it done. I added a custom function. I found it here
https://philipnewcomer.net/2012/10/add-post-categories-to-the-body-class-in-wordpress/

```
function pn_body_class_add_categories( $classes ) {

    // Only proceed if we're on a single post page
    if ( !is_single() )
        return $classes;

    // Get the categories that are assigned to this post
    $post_categories = get_the_category();

    // Loop over each category in the $categories array
    foreach( $post_categories as $current_category ) {

        // Add the current category's slug to the $body_classes array
        $classes[] = 'category-' . $current_category->slug;

    }

    // Finally, return the $body_classes array
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'pn_body_class_add_categories' );
```

After that, it was just basic, got the category Class from body, targeted single post class. I hope it helps someone.